# search substring in a string

Tags: c, string

Write a program that finds all instances of the specified pattern in the given string and replaces
them with another string. The base string, search pattern and the replacement string will be
provided by the user. I wrote such program, but something wrong with it  and i couldn't understand what.

> ```
> input:
>  enter the sentence: hello world
>  enter the word which u want to replace: world
> enter the new word: hello
>
> output:
> The word appears one times
> ```

```
#define SIZE 80

void newsentence(char a[], char b[], char c[], int n, int k);
void array(int f, int s, int g, char buff[], char b[], char c[], int n, int k);

int main()
{
    char a[SIZE], b[SIZE], c[SIZE];
    int k;

    printf("Enter the sentence: ");
    gets(a);
    printf("\nEnter the word which u want to replace: ");
    scanf("%s",b);
    printf("\nEnter the new word: ");
    scanf("%s",c);

    int n =0;
    char *temp;
    temp =a;

    while((temp =strstr(temp,b))!= NULL){
        n++;
        temp++;
        k = strstr(temp,b)-b;
    }
    printf("The word appears %d times",n);

    newsentence(a,b,c,n,k);
}

void newsentence(char a[], char b[], char c[], int n, int k)
{
    int f, s, g;
    char buff;

    f=strlen(a);
    s=strlen(b);
    g=strlen(c);

    strcpy(buff,a);

    array(f,s,g, buff,b,c,n,k);
}
void array(int f, int s, int g, char buff[], char b[], char c[], int n, int k)
{
    int i,j;
    int q;
    q = k +s - 1;

    for(j = 0; k<=q ;k++, j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(buff[k],b[j])==0){
            strcmp(buff[k],c[i]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("Yout new string is: %c",buff[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the division of the result of `strlen` with another? Does this code actually compile without warnings, for example `buff` seems wrongly defined and should produce errors.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Looks like she found something similar like `#define count(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` what helps if a is an array of arbitrary items and tried to use this in "string" context (but in a wrong way). Unfortunately there are a lot of other problems.

Comment: The code shows a lot of flaws and errors. To solve this I recommend to divide and conquer. (1) Divide the program in small chunks, take each chunks in its own program with a simple main that calls it with the intended arguments. This helps enormously because you have to *think* about the arguments. Additionally you can see how it works. (2) Use descriptive variable names. This improves readability but it also you *think* about your intention.

Comment: ok, thank u very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following function help you to replace first occurance

```
void str_find_replace(char *str, char *find, char *replace)
{
    size_t find_len,replace_len;
    char *str_end;

    find_len = strlen(find);
    replace_len = strlen(replace);
    str_end = strlen(str);

    while(*str){
        if(!strncmp(str,find,find_len) {
            memmove(str+replace_len,str+find_len, str_end - (str + find_len) + 1);
            memcpy(str,replace,replace_len);
            return;
        }
        str++;
    }
}
```

If you want to replace all the occurrences then use following function

```
void str_find_replace(char *str, char *find, char *replace)
{
    size_t find_len,replace_len;
    char *str_end;

    find_len = strlen(find);
    replace_len = strlen(replace);
    str_end = strlen(str);

    while(*str){
        if(!strncmp(str,find,find_len) {
            memmove(str+replace_len,str+find_len, str_end - (str + find_len) + 1);
            memcpy(str,replace,replace_len);
            str += replace_len;
            str_end = str + strlen(str);
            continue;
        }
        str++;
    }
}
```